# Stripe ignoring billing_cycle_anchor when creating a new subscription and an invoice is created straight away. Why is this happening?

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using Stripe in NodeJS to create subscirptions. I want an invoice to be generated near the end of the billing period. For example, if the billing period is 1-30 Septmeber, I want the invoice to be generated on 30 September. The API docs says that billing_cycle_anchor should do this. But it has no effect when I use it, as an invoice is generated straight away and the user is charged. Code example below.

```
stripeSubscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create({
            customer: id,
            items: [{ plan: planId }],
            billing_cycle_anchor: moment()
            .add('30', 'days')
            .unix();,
        });
```

How can I get monthly subscription to generate and charge at the end of the billing period?

Comment: I have the same issue. I'm using the latest Java Client and Stripe API

Comment: The issue with my code was that the '30' string should have been the integer 30. Make sure to check that the billing_cycle_anchor timestamp is in the future. The correct solution to my problem is below.
`stripeSubscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create({
            customer: id,
            items: [{ plan: planId }],
            billing_cycle_anchor: moment().add(30, 'days').unix(),
        });`

Answer (score 0):

Can billing_cycle_anchor be set to the 1st of January, regardless of when the user starts the subscription?

e.g.

```
this.currentYear = (new Date()).getFullYear();
this.newYear = (new Date(this.currentYear + 1 + '/01/01 00:01')).getTime()/1000;
```

Then in the function call:

```
firebase.default
            .firestore()
            .collection('users')
            .doc(user.uid)
            .collection('checkout_sessions')
            .add({
              price: 'price_BLAHBLAH',
              billing_cycle_anchor: this.newYear, //1672503000 01/01/2023 12:10 AM
              ...
            })
```